# RSpec - invalid space character causes undefined method ` should'?

Tags: ruby, rspec, atom-editor

I sporadically get an really annoying error when writing specs in RubyMine & Atom where it seems like there is an invalid space character so ruby evaluates the first (blank) character as a part of the method name.

```
1) Activity 
     Failure/Error: it { should belong_to :micropost }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method ` should' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Activity:0x007fd00e41bd20>
     # ./spec/models/activity_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Note the space in front of `' should'` in the error message.

I have tried turning on invisible characters and I can't see anything different than the normal space.

Deleting the first space inside the `it` block and hitting the space bar fixes the issue but it's pretty annoying to go back and fix the blocks all the time.

Any ideas about what is causing the error?

## Added

By suggestion I added opened the spec up in a hex editor. The offending bytes are `C2 A0`-

```
it {¬†should belong_to :micropost }
```

---

```
69 74 20 7B C2 A0 73 68 6F 75 6C 64 20 62 65 6C 6F 6E 67 5F 74 6F 20 3A 6D 69 63 72 6F 70 6F 73 74 20 7D
```

Comment: Next time it happens, check the script in a hex editor and figure out what bytes are in that location. That may provide a clue.

Comment: I opened the spec file up in a hex editor (Hex Fiend) and added the results - hexes are are a huge mystery to me though so I have no idea what to make of it.

Comment: A good hex editor will show you the plaintext and the hex side-by-side; the hex is just the hexadecimal representation of each byte. Bytes are represented by a value 0-255, which is represented in hex as 00-FF. A normal space character is byte 32, which is hex 20. See http://i.imgur.com/abhz3SW.png for an example. It may be easier to just copy-and-paste the offending text into an IRB session as a string and inspect it, the results of `str.chars` and `str.bytes`.

Comment: Oh, I just saw the edit with the offending bytes - `C2 A0` is the Unicode non-breaking space character. On OS X, this is inserted by pressing Option-Space - are you perhaps doing this by accident?

Comment: Yeah, I was - thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the most likely cause was that my fat butter fingers was hitting <kbd>alt (option)</kbd> + <kbd>spacebar</kbd>. Which also explains why it was happening even after I switched editors.

I solved the issue by downloading [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and activating `Non Breaking Space To Normal Space`.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/78245/how-to-disable-the-option-space-key-combination-for-non-breaking-spaces for a solution on how to disable that key combo on OS X. Not sure what OS you're on though!