# undefined method in controller action new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I'm getting a strange error message, not much information is given and i'm quite confused.

```
undefined method ` ' for #<User::PhoneNumbersController:0x007ff2259fa320>
```

*router.rb*

```
namespace :user do

    resources :phone_numbers, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

*controllers/user/phone_numbers_controller.rb*

```
class User::PhoneNumbersController < User::UserController

  def new
    @phonenumber = PhoneNumber.new
  end

end
```

*models/phone_number.rb*

```
class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

It's failing at this line: `@phonenumber = PhoneNumber.new`

Is my design pattern wrong?
the stack trace  doesn't say much...

**Thanks to Max's answer**

I indeed have "fallen victim to to the evil non-breaking space character" or NBSP. I had one on the left of the instance variable `@phonenumber`.

Comment: Where is the model `phone_number.rb` located?

Comment: models/phone_numbers.rb. All my models are under the models folder.

Comment: Is it `phone_number.rb` or `phone_numbers.rb`?

Comment: `phone_number.rb`. updated my question.

Comment: @Cyzanfar and if you remove the line does the error go away? try replacing  `PhoneNumber.new` with some `string` and see if the problem remains.. It might be some `.rb` file encoding issue..

Comment: just tried assigning it to an empty string `@phonenumber = ""`. still same error on the same line. What do you mean by encoding issue ? I've already created multitude of controller and this issue never happened before.

Comment: It's got to be something to do with the `User::` declaration

Comment: `User::UserController` Have you got `controllers/user/user_controller.rb`? (singular). It'd imagine it to be `User::UsersController`

Comment: Yes I do `controllers/user/user_controller.rb`, I also have a `controllers/users/` for the Devise specific controllers.

Comment: Okay thanks for the update!

Comment: No thanks to you for taking the time to help me. Any clues on the issue?

Comment: Waiting to see what `@max` says with his answer. I don't know about the issue he highlighted, so I'm interested to see where it arises etc. I personally think you could be nesting your resources rather than using a namespace

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have fallen victim to to the evil [non-breaking space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) or one of its cousins such as the hair space.

While visibly identical the Ruby parser does not treat the non-breaking space character `U+00A0` the same as the normal `U+0020` character. Ruby instead treats it as an identifier. Which is why you get `` undefined method ` ' ``.

Turn on the hidden characters in your editor and go hunting for those pesky NBSP's.

Comment: Nice phrase(*You have fallen victim to to the evil*) BTW!

Comment: Never hear about this issue before. Could you elaborate? I'm going to see how to "turn on the hidden characters" on my text editor

Comment: This has driven me to near insanity before.  I figured out how to search for them at the command line:  `grep -r -I -n "$(printf '\302\240')" .`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629580/rspec-invalid-space-character-causes-undefined-method-should

Comment: Btw, look at your keyboard shortcuts, in your text editor.  I had one in mine (Geany) to insert the non-breaking space on some key combo which i was hitting by accident sometimes.  I switched it off and haven't had any problems since.

Comment: Woahhh! Thank you @max! That worked-- I installed a package on my test editor that highlights those NBSP's and got rid of them. Amazing ;)

Comment: `@Cyzanfar` can you explain what the issue was? Where did you have one of those characters?

Comment: There is a keybinding for Atom to replace NBSP with  (Yeah Unicode has a poop character). https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/8080#issuecomment-163760779

Comment: that's fantastic, won't stay unnoticed anymore ;)